# Cron Jobs Fail to Trigger Node.js Script on External Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, cpanel

I have a `node.js` application on a Windows Server and a series of `cron` jobs setup via cPanel on an external CENTOS server. The `cron` jobs all target the URL of my node.js application using `wget`. I confirmed that the jobs are running according to the `cron` logs in WHM, but they are not causing the script on the other server to run as they should.

The format of the `cron` jobs are like this:

```
wget -q -O - "http://example.com/app?&param=1&param=2" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The result of the `cron` job should be the execution of the script on the other server. That script uses Puppeteer to scrape web pages, take screenshots, parse the results into RSS feeds, and create rss formatted XML files on the file system. Despite the `cron` jobs firing and targeting the right URLs, I have yet to see a single `cron` job result in a new image or xml file being created.

This leads me to wonder if there is something I don't know about when it comes to cPanel, `cron` jobs and `javascript`. I'm thinking maybe they won't work with URLs leading to `javascript` files, but if that were true then wouldn't I have the same problem when executing the same commands via SSH? I just tried one using the WHM terminal and it triggered the desired result.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to your node application and cron job runner. Be sure that your node application is triggered by logging into the console.

Whenever you do file operations, be sure that the user who runs your node application has permissions to write and read at the location that you have given. My guess is that your problem is about permissions.

Comment: What do you mean by "triggered by logging into the console?" The node app is always running on IIS like a website. The functions that take screenshots and write files are triggered whenever it receives a URL with the correct parameters. The user account used to create the files always belongs to either the IIS app pool or the IIS user both of which have sufficient permissions. The user is the same no matter where the get request comes from.

Comment: To correct, whenever your nodejs application is triggered by corn job, log it into the console at the beginning of the endpoint in the nodejs application to figure out whether there is web access or a file system operation problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues was due to the firewall on the IIS server. I added the remote IP address to the whitelist and now the cron jobs work.